# Sankhya vs Advaitha

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, advaita, sankhya

Can anyone please list out most common misconceptions between them? Are they same? View on division of parbrahamn? View on aatma? Which is the right one according to the Gita?

Comment: you need to put one question in a question. you are asking multiple questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't regarded as misconceptions, but as different intrepretions  (in its own context )that evolve (through open debates),though envisaged by sages , who accept the authority of Vedas(frigid texts/Substratum)

Although the original texts of most of astika schools are available , Kapila (proponent) sutras of sankhya philosophy(probably most earliest.. earlier than Bhagavad Gita , Brahma Sutras ) are nonextant.

So Ishwara Krishna's sankhya karika is the available primary source,( based on which texts like Vachaspathi Mishra's sankya tattva kaumudi , Gaudapadacharyas sankya bhashyam ,etc are there.)Still,you may find different schools of sankya philosophy, holding on to different intrepretions of sankhya.They aren't viewed as misconceptions,,but they coexist.

'Sankya' in Bhagavad Gita connotes Jnana Marg and not the sankya philosophy.

**Are they same?** They are in equal terms wrt. to Bondage and Liberation. (Kapila Gita philosophical dialogue  that details Brahma Vidya )

**View on atma**..Purusha is Atman in Sankya , efficient cause (Nimitha karana)and Prakrithi is the material  cause (..dualism)
Purusha is neither an evolute nor is evolved (consciousness),Mula Prakrithi(Non consciousness/Material cause) is only an evolute  but is not evolved (Primordial).
So Purusha is the Atman of Vedas in the context of Prakrithi,which manifests through Prakrithi(and thus become s many)

Advaita says there is only a single Atman that is all pervading.which is real . cosmos(Matter) is an apparent projection .

Tattvas of sankya and the terms(nouns) of Advaita arent coined in them , but are taken from Vedic literature.

They contradict wrt. to the theory of creation (Parinama Vada, Vivartha Vada) and wrt to no. of pramanaas they agree.

**Division of Parabrahman**..

Chandhogya Upanishad 6.2.3

> tad aikshata bahu syAm, prajAyeya" Let me be born (as many)

Sankya says Prakrithi evolves , thus multiplies(vikrithi) (influenced by Purusha), whereas
Advaita says Multiplicity is an apparent projection of Brahman (Atman) caused by Maya.

**which one is right according to Gita**?Different  interpretations coexist and they hold good in their own context